# Which OpenAPI client sdk for loopback4 and angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, loopbackjs, openapi, loopback4

We are currently migrating a `loopback3` application to `loopback4`.
The migration of the server is steight forward, but migrating the `angular` client seems become an issue because of the "sdk".

For `loopback3` we used [@mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder) to generate a client sdk for `angular6+`. This project seems reaced end-of-life and is not compatible with `loopback4`.

Generating the sdk for `loopback3` worked for us that way:

package.json of server:

```
"scripts": {
    "gen-sdk": "node ./node_modules/@mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder/bin/lb-sdk src/server.js ../frontend/src/app/shared/sdk --wipe=enabled"
}
```

The generator starts a copy of the server, reads different internal metadata and writes the generated files to the client project - as far i can see it does not make use of the `swagger.json` provided by `loopback3`.

We are searching for an alternative sdk to use with `loopback4`. The backend provides a `openapi.json` to describe the endpoints.

Which sdk do you use in your `angular` projects (ideally written in `TypeScript`)? Is there a sdk which generated code is mostly compatible with `@mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder`?

So far I found and tested the following projects to generate a openapi client:

- [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)

  - **con**: is written in Java
  - **con**: throws NullpointerExceptions all the time (maybe our openapi.json is not correct, but this generator does not provide useful error messages)
- [ng-openapi-gen](https://github.com/cyclosproject/ng-openapi-gen)

  - **pro**: is written in `TypeScript`
  - **con**: the generated operation names are really strage, maybe only in combination with `loopback4`?
  - **con**: the project does not seem to be very active

Which `angular` setup do you suggest to talk to an `loopback4` rest backend?

Answer (score 0):

The Loopback 4 project addresses this issue with their documentation on [Building an Angular Application from OpenAPI Specification](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Building-frontend-angular-application.html)

A summary of the steps are:

1. In your Loopback 4 project generate the openapi-spec from your controllers with the command `npm run openapi-spec` to generate an OpenAPI JSON file.
2. In your Angular application use the ng-openapi-gen package to generate Angular API stubs from the OpenAPI JSON file in the previous step. For example:

`ng-openapi-gen --input <path-to-openapi-json> --output <angular-app-path>/src/app/api`

The contents of the `<angular-app-path>/src/app/api` directory contain models for the API to use within Angular. See their documentation for a complete example.